# How to insert multiple begin end inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I realized that I cannnot use GO inside stored procedure.

I have multiple processes where I need to drop view and then create view etc.

How do I create a stored procedure without getting error?

Basically, this is not a nested process, but process just goes from top to bottom because I am dropping views, creating views then later creating tables.

Bottom is basic structure of two processes, but I will have at least 10+ processes with similar pattern.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Create_Views_Tables_Nov2021

AS
BEGIN
set nocount on

begin
    begin
        drop view [dbo].[vw_tblSage_GLDETAIL_0001] 
    end

begin
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_tblSage_GLDETAIL_0001]  
    AS
    SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[tblSage_GLDETAIL_1_1_Stage]
    union 
    SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[tblSage_GLDETAIL_1_2_Stage]
end

end
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you should default to using UNION ALL rather than UNION as duplicate removal is not often needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BEGIN...END` aren't batch separators. T-SQL doesn't have a built in batch separator (`GO` is not part of T-SQL). If you want to run the statements in their own batches, you'll have to use deferred statements by executing them with `sys.sp_executesql`.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Create_Views_Tables_Nov2021

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'DROP VIEW [dbo].[vw_tblSage_GLDETAIL_0001];';

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    SET @SQL = N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_tblSage_GLDETAIL_0001]' + @CRLF +
               N'AS' + @CRLF +
               N'SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[tblSage_GLDETAIL_1_1_Stage]' + @CRLF +
               N'UNION --Should this not be UNION ALL?' + @CRLF +
               N'SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[tblSage_GLDETAIL_1_2_Stage];'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

END
```

Comment: Thank you. What is @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10); for? Regards to UNION, I thought by having UNION, it only retrieves unique value (deleting dups), no?

Comment: CRLF means Carriage Return, Line Feed, @Java . And correct, that's what `UNION` means, however, that is normally the incorrect choice with `SELECT *`.

Comment: Why not just use a multi-line string literal instead of all that string concatenation?

Comment: [Why I define my Carriage Returns and Line Breaks as variables in Dynamic SQL](https://wp.larnu.uk/why-i-declare-my-carriage-returns-and-line-breaks-in-dynamic-sql/) @DavidBrowne-Microsoft .

Answer (score 2):

If you run into a problem that seems to be a catch 22, this is a good indication that your using the wrong approach.

Instead of dropping and recreating your view, you should instead be using:

```
ALTER VIEW vw_tblSage_GLDETAIL_0001
AS
SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[tblSage_GLDETAIL_1_1_Stage]
union 
SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[tblSage_GLDETAIL_1_2_Stage]
```

to change your view.

If you can't be sure that the view already exists before hand (it's always good to make this assumption), then use:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW vw_tblSage_GLDETAIL_0001
AS
SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[tblSage_GLDETAIL_1_1_Stage]
union 
SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[tblSage_GLDETAIL_1_2_Stage]
```